# Writing text file in Ant with UTF-16 encoding and BOM

Tags: java, encoding, ant, byte-order-mark

I need to generate a file in my ant project that looks like this:

```
FF FE 5B 00 6F 00 6C 00|65 00 64 00 62 00 5D 00 |˙ţ[ o l e d b ]
0D 00 0A 00 3B 00 20 00|45 00 76 00 65 00 72 00 |. . ;   E v e r
```

The point is:

- start with BOM
- line endings 0D 0A
- UTF-16 encoding

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<echo  file='${oledir}/cst.udl' append='false' encoding='UTF-16LE'>
[oledb]
;  Ever
</echo>
```

But the BOM is missing and line endings are not OK because I use Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work for me, Ant 1.8.0 on Java 1.6.0:

```
<concat destfile='cst.udl' append='false' outputencoding='UnicodeLittle'>
<string>[oledb]
; Ever</string>
<filterchain>
    <fixcrlf eol="dos"/>
</filterchain>
</concat>
```

Uses the Ant [`concat` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) with a [filterchain](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) to enforce the DOS line endings.
The [`UnicodeLittle` encoding](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) includes the BOM in the output, whereas `UTF-16LE` does not.

(Note that in the text of your echo task you start the text with a newline:

```
<echo ... >
text
</echo>
```

whereas

```
<echo ... >text</echo>
```

contains no newlines.)